# css causes radio button not to appear

Tags: html, css

I have CSS :

```
form{}

form input,
form select,
form textarea {
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
}

form input:focus,
form textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #c94663;
}

form ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}

form :-moz-placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}

form ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}

form :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}
```

When I create my form all the form elements (e.g input type=text, submit...) are created correctly, but when I say `input type="radio"` it does not show-up the radio button and gives me output as [SEE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt67b/), If I remove line :

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

it shows radio button but it affects all of my form elements, so I can not figure out how can I see radio buttons.

Comment: can you please provide the fiddle

Comment: the above link SEE HERE is pointing to fiddle

Comment: What exactly do you have the `-webkit-appearance: none;` in there for? Without it the radio buttons are rendered just fine... http://jsfiddle.net/Wt67b/3/

Comment: @xec, I'm guessing user3310291 is using a webkit browser. Radio buttons render in Firefox.

Comment: @xec <input type="radio" is not a radio element? This is because you mentioned under my post - there is no radio element. Have you seen the fiddle?

Comment: @Dipaks `<input type="radio">` is an `input` element. To select it in CSS you would do `input[type="radio"] {...}` as opposed to `radio {...}` as you had in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this, you are applying style to all the input tags.

```
form input, form select, form textarea {
       border-radius: 0.4em; 
      -webkit-appearance: none;
       border: solid 1px #ddd;
      padding: 0.5em;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

instead use `form input[type=text]` which will target only the text boxes

```
form input[type=text],form input[type=submit],form input[type=reset], form select, form textarea {
           border-radius: 0.4em; 
          -webkit-appearance: none;
           border: solid 1px #ddd;
          padding: 0.5em;
          width: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but wouldn't be this http://jsfiddle.net/Wt67b/6/ good, because style of _submit_ and _reset_ buttons is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could be choose more specific by using `<input> type Attribute` Method. See the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt67b/5/)**.

```
form input[type="radio"]{ width:auto;}
```

Comment: I'm bit confused, in your [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt67b/5/), the radio button is not select-able, how can that be selected??

Comment: seems you checked on Chrome. yes it selected. I've added a bit of JS code so you can see that clickEvent is working while click on checkbox. check the new DEMO. http://jsfiddle.net/Wt67b/7/